# ActiveRecord Association: one-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**CASE**

I am working on a model which is composed of the following tables:

- users
- companies
- comments (join table)

The relations I am looking for are:

- A user `has_many` comments.
- A company `has_many` comments.
- A company `has_many` users.
- but a user **does not necessarily** `belongs_to` a company.

Meaning basically that users would be able to login, reference their information such as name, last_name, etc... But a user could be a simple visitor or could be a company's employee.

e.g, users will have the choice, but not mandatory, to assign themselves a company they currently `belongs_to`.

---

**APPROACH**

I was thinking in a way to accomplish this:

Creating 2 users tables, one could be *employees* the other one *visitors* for instance. But it doesn't seem to cover the case where you change your status, for example, if you don't want to `belongs_to` a company anymore, this approach seems inefficient.

Or using a boolean column in my users table, `"employee?", :boolean, default: false`. I am not sure how to handle this tho. How to switch from false to true and assign a user to a company and vise versa?

---

**QUESTION**

Is there a way through one single users table to handle both status -visitors and employees- and dynamically switch from a category to another?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do it with two steps:

1.Make `belongs_to` relation optional:

```
# User model
belongs_to :company, optional: true
```

2.Make scopes and methods to differ visitors and employees:

```
# User model
scope :visitors, -> { where(company: nil) }
scope :employees, -> { where.not(company: nil) }

def visitor?
  company_id.nil?
end

def employee?
  !visitor?
end
```

That's it. Now you can do like this:

```
User.visitors
User.employees

User.find(id).visitor?
```

Comment: thanks for this, I have thought about scope. I am not sure about what's happening under the hood with the following tho:  { where.not(location: nil) }

Comment: Sorry, it was misspelling. It should be `{ where.not(company: nil) }` which just opposite to `{ where(company: nil) }`.

Comment: that's what I thought, thanks for the edit. So a simple company foreign key on users' table will do the job thanks to the scope? No additional join table?

Comment: EDIT: This previous question because in fine, the idea would be to be able to do a `User.find(id).employee?.company.name` for instance

Comment: You may do different logic depending on user type: `user.employee? ?  company.name : nil`. Also you may this kind of logic to User model: `def company_name; employee? company.name : nil end`